# The khanacedemy tag - yay, nay or burninate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just rejected a tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt edit for the [khanacademy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/khanacademy) tag.

The reason I gave was "Tag is for a website, as opposed to hardware or software. Rejected as per FAQ. Feel free to bring up on meta.su if it hasn't already"

Now, as I see it, issues between a browser and the website are fine for SU. On the other hand, having a tag for a website, specifically is contrary to the part of the FAQ that goes "this site is not about websites"

Now, do we go remove the tag as well, or is there a compelling argument for the tag?

Comment: I understand the rationale behind your decision. However I hope you will consider reversing it. Even if the question whether the tag should remain or be removed is still being debated, you could accept the wiki and wiki excerpt and allow them to describe the tag for as long as it is allowed to remain in the system. If the tag is removed in the future, wouldn't the wiki and excerpt be automatically removed as well? **PS:** One of the 5 questions tagged with _khanacademy_ was tagged by a different user (the asker of that question).

Comment: That was helpful in closing some questions

Comment: Link to the tag: [tag:khanacademy]

Comment: @random so the tag is helpful after all, eh? :P

Comment: Oh, i made a spot decision on the tag wiki. I feel however, that i wanted to be open on that. I just don't think unilateral decisions are something a user should take. In my case, with a binary decision, the best option was to reject and ask - i could have probably supplied you with your tag wiki contents from history i think. This is ahy i asked a question here ;p

Comment: Get rid of the tag, please.  It's like tagging programming questions on StackOverflow with the professor's name, it doesn't contribute to any desirable taxonomy.  A good question will carry other, more useful tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tag is set for deletion when the questions it was recently tagged on to are also deleted. They're the typical, "what *could* I try (when I haven't even done a thing and want you all to just heap upon me a cart and horse full of your finest silks)?" type of questions that field all sorts of apps and programs and only use Khan Academy as an example. Not constructive.

The one [posted today](https://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-cannot-render-icons-from-font-awesome-webfont-set) is less about the website and more on the browser. It was only used as an example of where the problem is happening among others.

When questions are largely about the use or unuse of a website or web app, they belong on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/question).

Examples aren't meant for tags and an example will be made of this tag.

Comment: I noticed you have reworded the question to make it explicit that the problem is with the browser and not the website. Yet it was closed as off topic 8 hours after your rewording. I also don't understand the point you're trying to make here in your answer. Is it (a) the question should be allowed to remain open as it's more about the browser? or (b) the question merits closing (or migration) as it's concentrating on a single website?

Comment: If the question is about the website, then it would be off topic. But since there are no other examples of this happening, users would see it as that. Reworded to be more on topic for the site, but lack of examples localises it to just that one site. If it's just one site, then it would move toward close

Answer (score 5):

The answer seems to be burninate  - so self answering to close the question

Comment: It maybe helpful in filtering and closing questions in the future, as pointed out by @random :) Also, would you be able to reverse the decision and allow the tag to be described as long as it is going to remain in the system? :D Not a big deal but just wondering if it's possible to reverse decisions.

Comment: not directly. I was intending to use meta to work around that by asking you to redo the tag edits and accepting them ;p.

Comment: I sent it in :)

Comment: butif its an invalid tag, is there a point? unused tags do get removed frm the system after some time.

Comment: It's currently used by 5 questions. What is the definition of "unused tags"? Anyway I see no harm in accepting the wiki even if the tag is questionable. If the tag is later removed, so goes the wiki - but until then the wiki could serve the purpose of describing it. I have no objection to later removal of the tag, but I think it's reasonable to expect the tag to be described during its lifetime, no matter how short it may be. And I have no problem putting in effort to describe a questionable tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the only reason the tag existed before ADTCs question was as an anchor for questions along the lines of "How do I do stuff like this site".

[ADTCs question](https://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-not-displaying-icons-in-khanacademy) is simply "Why does Firefox not work properly with this site", something that would be better directed at the sites authors than SU.

Neither of these types of question actually *need* a tag to describe the site.  It is simply a near redundant piece of information.

We are not here to provide support for websites themselves, nor how to emulate a website.

As such I vote for burnination.

Comment: I hope the question can remain. I had added an issue at the website's own support page and I am referencing my own SU question there, so I would like the link to remain valid at least until the problem is solved, even if the question gets closed. Anyway the purpose of asking this question in SU was to see if this problem (which only occurs in Firefox) can be fixed by doing something **on my side**, rather than on the website's side.

Comment: The question... maybe... though it may be better off on [webapps.se] as it's more about a website than a software application.  The tag though, now that I would burninate with *extreme* prejudice.

Comment: I had no idea about Web Applications SE or even Programmers.SE until just few minutes ago. _So many categories!..._ Anyway how about migrating then?

Comment: You can flag your question for moderator attention to see if they think it is a viable candidate for migration.  Out of preference do not simply repost it there.  But yes, there used to be 3 stackexchange sites, now more appear daily...